# Is it okay to use .Query<table_name> when updating SQLite using Xamarin?

Tags: sqlite, xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms

I have taken over some code and I see that database updates are performed like this:

```
dbcon = DependencyService.Get<ISQLite>().GetConnection();

public void UpdateAnswered(string id)
{
   lock(locker)
   {
      dbcon.Query<Phrase>("UPDATE Phrase SET Answered = Answered + 1 " +
                                               "WHERE Id = ?", id);
   }
}
```

I am new to using SQLite with Xamarin but it looks strange to me that this update is handled with a dbcon.Query and that the table name is passed as . Can someone confirm is this the optimal way to handle a table update? Also why is it coded as a query with the table name being passed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### `Update<T>`

This method allows you to pass in an instance of an object that this stored in the database which has a primary key. SQLite then recognizes the primary key and updates the rest of the object's values.

You would just call `connection.Update( phrase );` where the `phrase` is an instance of the `Phrase` class with properties you want to set. Be aware that **all columns** except ID will be updated.

### `Query<T>`

Performs a query and returns the results. The type parameter specifies the type of the items returned. This is most appropriate for `SELECT` queries.

### `Execute`

This returns the number of affected rows by the query as an `int`. This is probably the best choice for your `UPDATE` query after the `Update<T>` method.

### `ExecuteScalar<T>`

Use for queries that return scalar types - like `COUNT`, etc., where `T` is the type of the value.

In summary, `Update` is the most natural way to **update a row** in the database (with an instance you have), but `Query<T>` and `Execute<T>` are very useful if you just want to `UPDATE` **one column** like in your example.

Comment: Hi,  thanks for your detailed reply.  As it's a SQL statement I am thinking Execute might be more appropriate.  But then why is there a <T> for execute because surely it could execute any command?

Comment: Sorry, it turned out I have actually mistaken the two methods. I have rewritten the answer with the right method descriptions :-) ....